# Error with Firestore Increment Value for Large Integers

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experiencing an issue with Firestore's `FieldValue.increment()` function when using large integer values. The increment works correctly for smaller numbers, but it produces incorrect results, even negative values, for numbers above approximately 2148 million (2148000000).

I have the following code that increments a counter called `test` within the Firestore database. The increment function works perfectly for small `incrementValue` numbers. However, from the number 2148 million (2148000000) onwards, a calculation error occurs and the increment can even give negative values. I'm using 0 as a starting `test` value in Firestore.  Here are some examples of the results:

**Example 1:**

- Initial `test` value in Firestore = 0
- Increment Value = 1000
- Expected Result = 1000
- Final test value in Firestore = 1000 (Ok)

**Example 2:**

- Initial `test` value in Firestore = 0
- Increment Value = 2148000000
- Expected Result = 2148000000
- Final test value in Firestore = -2146967296 (Error)

**Example 3:**

- Initial `test` value in Firestore = 0
- Increment Value = 10000000000
- Expected Result = 10000000000
- Final test value in Firestore = 1410065408 (Error)

**Code:**

```
      Future<bool> incrementTest() async {
        
        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
    
        int incrementValue  = 2148000000;
    
        DocumentReference doc = db
          .collection('testing')
          .doc('increment');
    
        batch.update(doc, {
          'test':  FieldValue.increment(incrementValue),
        });
        log('Test incrementValue: $incrementValue');
    
        try {
          await batch.commit();
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          log('$e');
          return false;
        }
      }
```

**Observations:**

- The issue persists with both WriteBatch and direct doc.update()
  operations.
- [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#increment) states a limit of -2^63 to    2^63-1 for
  integer operations, which is much higher than the    problematic
  value.
- The exact value where the error begins to appear is 2147483648 which is equivalent to 2^32 / 2 (32-bit signed integer)

**Questions:**

- Is there a specific limitation on Firestore's increment function
  that's causing this behavior?
- How can I reliably increment counters with values potentially
  exceeding 2148 million while avoiding this error?

Comment: What *exactly* does this code do, if not what you expect?  Please edit the question to provide a specific example and the results that don't seem correct.  We should be able to reproduce the specific result using the code and data you provide.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I included a description of the code in the question. What you would expect is that 0 + 2148000000 results in 2148000000 and the result that appears is -2146967296

Comment: If you are using 0 as a starting value in the existing document, could you edit the question to make that clear?

Comment: @DougStevenson, updated. Actually the error happens for any number that is in the database. In this case, if there is no number in the base, it will take zero as the initial value

Comment: The point is to show a reproducible example, and not leave it up to the reader to guess how to set this up to get "even negative numbers".  Please be specific on your use case and results. To be clear - I'm not doubting that something is wrong.  It just needs to be stated how exactly to get a consistently incorrect result.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I included the initial value in Firestore and some examples for clarity. I also added an important observation about the limit number.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is not with the firebase but is limited to `Dart` ,

as a fact that the maximum value that can be represented by a 32-bit signed integer is 2147483647 .
the sane is causing the issue here ,as in Dart the default data type for integers is int, which is a 32-bit signed integer.

```
   Future<bool> incrementTest() async {
   // WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
  
    Int64 incrementValue = Int64(2148000000); //here use the Int64 data type 
  
    DocumentReference doc = db.collection('testing').doc('increment');
  
    await transaction.update(doc,{
      'test' : incrementValue+1
    });
    log('Test incrementValue: $incrementValue');
  
    try {
      await batch.commit();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      log('$e');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

i am currently unable to run this in flutter environment so i welcome any suggestion by any one .

Comment: Thanks. Int64(2148000000) is not a num supported by FieldValue.increment and it is not in the standard dart libraries. According to the flutter documentation, the default implementation of int is 64-bit two's complement integers

Comment: please file bug as @DougStevenson suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a specific limitation on Firestore's increment function that's causing this behavior?

I was unable to reproduce the problem (your second test case) at all using firebase-admin on nodejs, both on the emulator and the actual cloud service.  This leads me to believe that the problem is likely with the Flutter SDK and not the Firestore service itself.  You should file a bug with your steps to reproduce on the [Firebase Flutter SDK GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire).  You can see the source code yourself [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore) if you want to dig in further and propose a specific change.

> How can I reliably increment counters with values potentially exceeding 2148 million while avoiding this error?

If the increment operation doesn't work the way you expect, you can perform an atomic increment by using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).  This will let you read the document, modify the number in memory, then write the modified value back to the document.  If you don't need the update to be atomic, then don't even bother with the transaction, and just read/modify/write the document as you would normally.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I need atomic values and offline use cases. According to your suggestion, I included a bug report in https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12318

Comment: If you found this answer helpful at all, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as correct.